# Room query that should return LiveData always returns NULL

Tags: android, sqlite, android-livedata

I want to create a login screen in android using Room/SQLLite.
Once my login activity is launched, a user object will be inserted in the database.

When pressing on the login button, I want to look for the user by the username I filled in.
Then I will check if the password that I gave in, is the correct password.
Based on that I will go to another activity or I will show an error message.

But this is going wrong, the next code is always returning NULL, so I will always end up showing the error message.

```
UserWithWorkorders userWithWorkorders = ie4ViewModel.getUserWithWorkorders(username.getText().toString()).getValue();
```

Here is the query in the UserDao. As you can see it returns LiveDate.

```
 @Query("SELECT * FROM User WHERE username =:username")
 LiveData<UserWithWorkorders> getUserWithWorkorders(String username);
```

Here is the onCreate() of my Login activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        IE4ViewModel ie4ViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(IE4ViewModel.class);

        User user = new User("John", "Doe", "john", "doe");
        ie4ViewModel.insertUser(user);

        final Button loginButton = findViewById(R.id.loginButton);
        final EditText username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        final EditText password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        final TextView errorMessage = findViewById(R.id.errorMessage);


        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UserWithWorkorders userWithWorkorders = ie4ViewModel.getUserWithWorkorders(username.getText().toString()).getValue();

                if (userWithWorkorders != null) {
                    if(userWithWorkorders.user.getPassword().equals(password.getText().toString())){
                        Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WorkordersActivity.class);
                        i.putExtra("userObject", userWithWorkorders);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }
                    else {
                        errorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    errorMessage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });

        ie4ViewModel.getUsersWithWorkorders().observe(this, new Observer<List<UserWithWorkorders>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<UserWithWorkorders> usersWithWorkorders) {
                if (usersWithWorkorders != null && usersWithWorkorders.size() > 0) {

                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? If there is any other code, you'd like to see, please let me know.
Or in other words: how do I retrieve an object in my android activity from a SQLLite database using Room if the Dao query is returning a LiveData object?

Comment: So I found out I will need an observer to fetch the user with the username, but I haven't figured out yet how to.
If someone could help on that one?

Answer (score 1):

For this line of code, you dont need to make it return observable.

```
UserWithWorkorders userWithWorkorders = ie4ViewModel.getUserWithWorkorders(username.getText().toString()).getValue();
```

**simply declare a method in your viewmodel like that.**

```
public UserWithWorkorders getUserWithWorkorders(String value){
//get result from DAO.
}
```

**Also make your DAO method return UserWithWorkorders**

Now call this method in your activity as you are already doing it.

```
 UserWithWorkorders userWithWorkorders = ie4ViewModel.getUserWithWorkorders(username.getText().toString()).getValue();
```

**Be fully sure that your database has some data to return.**